# Can I override the value returned by require() in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, require

For testing purposes, I want to use `require('whatever.js')` to return an arbitrary content rather than having it actually load the file.

```
// made up code
var AAA = {}; 
require.setFor('./whatever.js', AAA); 
var BBB = require('./whatever.js'); 
console.assert(AAA === BBB);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Simply overwrite the `require` function:

```
var realRequire = require;
require = function (what) {
    return realRequire('mocked-' + what);
}
```

You could use a lookup table for your mocks as well and call `realRequire()` if no mock exists.

Comment: Did that help? Or is anything missing?